# Battery Charge and Discharge Time Calculations

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, electrical, math

I am performing some calculations but struck with confusion whether I am doing it correct or wrong due to contradictions of these calculations on different calculators websites. I hope here someone will help me with the validation of my calculations.

```
Battery Capacity            = 150 Ah
Battery Nominal Voltage     = 666 V
Efficiency Charge/Discharge = 0.87
Power Demand                = 100 kW
Current Demand              = 150 A


Battery Discharge Time = (Battery Capacity x Battery Voltage x Efficiency ) / Power Demand
Battery Discharge Time = (150 x 666 x 0.87) / 100000
Battery Discharge Time = 0.87 Hours
Battery Discharge Time = 51 Minutes
```

Alternative Method

```
Battery Discharge Time = (Battery Capacity x Efficiency) / Current Demand
Battery Discharge Time = (150 *0.87)/150
Battery Discharge Time = 0.87 Hours
Battery Discharge Time = 51 Minutes
```

**Q1) If above both calculations are correct does it mean that I can constantly draw 100 kW from the battery for 51 minutes?**

**Q2) This [website](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-battery-life) tells a different story for calculating a run time when you put 150 Ah and 100000 W Load = 0.015 Hour Run time**

**Q3) What is 10 in the equation given on this [website](https://www.digikey.co.uk/en/resources/conversion-calculators/conversion-calculator-battery-life) for calculating run time. Runtime = (10 * Ampere Hours) / Load in Watts**

Thank You

Comment: Does your battery support that high C-rate?

Comment: Yes, Up to 6C under normal temperature conditions. But I prefer to perform above calculations under 1C rate.

Comment: Then 51 minutes seems reasonable.